# What are the rules mixing display Flex and Block?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Ionic is mixing flex and block displays. What are the rules for this kind of code :

```
<div class="d-flex">...</div>
<div class="d-block">...</div>
<div class="d-flex">...</div>
<div class="d-block">...</div>
```

Where d-flex and d-block are respectively flex and block displays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
display: flex
```

Tells the browser the element is a flexbox ***container***, which affects how its children should render. Since **d-block is a sibling and not a child element**, they don't actually mix with each other, and there's no particular rules for their respective behavior towards each other.